# Flask-bootstrap customizing Flask-security

Tags: python, flask, flask-security, flask-bootstrap

I am using Flask-security and I have not been able to integrate Flask-bootstrap in order to customize the user interface of the login, register, and other pages.

The project is hosted here:
https://github.com/fbenavides69/control-escolar

I have installed via pip the packages and can render the login, register and other pages, yet for some reason, I can not get them to render user bootstrap. I have followed the recommendations on c/p the security pages under the templates directory in the application, to override the look and feel, yet have not had any success.

Can someone please point me to what I am missing?

Here is the code for the login_user.html:

```
{% extends "layout.html" %}

{% block body %}
    {{super()}}

    {% include "navbar.html" %}

    {% block content %}
        {{super()}}

        {% from "security/_macros.html" import render_field_with_errors, render_field %}
        {% from "security/_form_macros.html" import render_field %}
        <div class="container">
        {% include "security/_messages.html" %}
        <h1>{{ _('Login') }}</h1>
        <form action="{{ url_for_security('login') }}" method="POST" name="login_user_form">
          {{ login_user_form.hidden_tag() }}
          {{ render_field_with_errors(login_user_form.email) }}
          {{ render_field_with_errors(login_user_form.password) }}
          {{ render_field_with_errors(login_user_form.remember) }}
          {{ render_field(login_user_form.next) }}
          {{ render_field(login_user_form.submit) }}
        </form>
        {% include "security/_menu.html" %}
        </div>

    {% endblock content %}

{% endblock body %}
```

Here is the layout.html:

```
{% extends "bootstrap/base.html" %}

{% block html_attribs %} 
    lang="sp" 
{% endblock %}
{% block metas %}
    <meta charset="utf-8">
{% endblock %}
```

Here is the file structure under which the templates are stored:

```
application
+-site
  +-templates
    +-security
      +- login_user.html
      +- register_user.html
```

Here the code for the init file:

```
''' Flask Application Factory

    Blueprint Flask application using the factory pattern,
    with configuration setup and blueprint module registration
'''
from flask import Flask
from flask_bootstrap import Bootstrap
from flask_security import Security
from flask_security import SQLAlchemyUserDatastore
from flask_debugtoolbar import DebugToolbarExtension
from flask_admin import Admin
from flask_admin.contrib.sqla import ModelView
from .models import db
from .models import User
from .models import Role
from .admin import admin


def create_app():
    ''' create_app

        input:
            None

        output:
            app -- flask web application instance

        Read configuration values in the following order:
            1) default, values which can be overwritten later
            2) intance, for your eyes only not stored in repo values
            3) environment, selectable values from:
                - development
                - stagging
                - production

        Setup web interface with Bootstrap framework
    '''

    # Initialize app
    app = Flask(__name__, instance_relative_config=True)

    # Load default config values
    app.config.from_object('config.default')
    # Load instance config values not stored in repo
    app.config.from_pyfile('config.py')
    # Load environment config values
    app.config.from_envvar('APP_CONFIG_FILE')

    # Create database connection
    db.init_app(app)

    # Instantiate Admin section
    admin.init_app(app)

    # Initialize bootstrap
    Bootstrap(app)

    # Setup Flask-Security
    security = Security(app, SQLAlchemyUserDatastore(db, User, Role))

    # Debug = True to enable the toolbar
    toolbar = DebugToolbarExtension(app)

    # Load blueprint modules
    from application.site.routes import mod as site
    from application.api.routes import mod as api

    # Register blueprint modules for use
    app.register_blueprint(site)
    app.register_blueprint(api, url_prefix='/api')

    return app
```

Answer (score 2):

Turns out, the 'templates' directory had to be placed directly under the 'application' folder for this to work:

```
application
  +-site
  +-templates
    +-security
```